# How to style RowEditing plugin

Tags: extjs6-classic

When activating the row editing plugin, the padding is bigger than usual:

[image]

Any idea of what can be affecting the layout or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid is inside a form definition. It inherited the `fieldDefaults`, so I had to move them inside the fieldset definition and leave the grid outside of it:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'test-form',

    layout: 'vbox',
    bodyPadding: 20,
    fieldDefaults: { //defined here will affect the roweditor plugin
        labelAlign: 'top',
        margin: 20
    },

   items: [
      { 
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        //fieldDefaults should be moved here and leave the grid untouched
        items: [...]
      },
      {
         xtype: 'grid',
         [...]
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom theme? It looks like the theme variables for rowediting are modified.
You can write changing the following variable: [$grid-row-editor-padding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.html#css_var-S-$grid-row-editor-padding)

Details on how to manage theme variables here: [Theming Ext JS](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html). You could also use the Sencha Themer tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a grid inside a form: it was inheriting the bodypadding and other styles. I moved the 'fieldDefaults' definition and problem solved.